# SSL Support in quill for Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, quill

I have been using quill for Cassandra. does quill support any config key to connect Cassandra cluster with SSL certs i.e client to node encryption?
if yes what is the that config key.

quill version 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `db.session.withSSL=true`